# Store PK Id or Name when having JSON Column in DB?

Tags: json, sql-server

I have a table that has a JSON column that holds all the non common specs of a product.

For instance I may have

cellphone and I will store the screen size in this json column as I may have another product (pc case) that has no screen at all.

```
{screenSize: "6 inches" }
```

However some products I have a pre-defined list of options so in the above example I might have another table in my db

ScreenSizesTbl (in my real db this is more generic to hold all the predefined options for all products)

```
id  Name
1   6 inches
2   5 inches
```

Should I store the name or the id?

```
{screenSize: "6 inches" } or     {screenSize: 1 }
```

If I do the latter then I would just get the name on the fly when pulling this information out. The advantage I see of this is that if I change the name to "6 Inches" then I don't have to do a data fix.

The downside I see, is if I am looking at the raw data I just see all the ids and not sure if I can really do a join on a json property to an id on a table.

I am using sql server 2017 so it has json support but I am not sure if something like joining what I would need is supported.

Answer (score 0):

> The downside I see, is if I am looking at the raw data I just see all
>   the ids and not sure if I can really do a join on a json property to
>   an id on a table.

That is a sign of a good, normalized database. Your table should be lots and lots of ID's that join to other tables and then the raw value is only stored in a single table somewhere. There are tons of queries that I write daily that require 3+ joins to get from a main table to a lookup table that provides me with a raw string value.

An example of what you should do is:

You have a product table (with product_id as PK) that contains product name, createddatetime, etc., an attributes table (with attribute_id as PK) that contains things like 'screen size', 'cores', etc. but no values, then you have a table that matches those values together and assigns a numeric/string value.

So your table ends up being:

```
Product_ID    Attribute_ID    Value 
1             1               6in 
1             2               2600Hz 
1             3               Pepperoni 
1             4               Blue
```

And you have to join to product to get the product name and join to attribute to get the attribute name. I have seen Value tables where each value has an ID and you have to join on that as well.

There absolutely cases where you need to store JSON, but it can be a pain to parse out values for joining and leveraging indexes for fast retrieval.

Comment: Yea I agree totally with your first statement, what I was getting at is because it is in a column of json, was not sure if in this case it may not be possible to join the JSON columns. I originally thought of doing it like you specified it but I do have some fields that are non defined fields and are filled in by the person uploading the product(ie a model number). I would have to think it over again but I also would like to see what the solution would be if I stick with json as if I change I may have to do more work reserving my code.